# Ruby on Rails Sort Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

My database is displaying properly, but the sort is not working.

In my controller, I have index defined as this

```
def index
  @player = Roster.sorted
end
```

And in my "Roster" model I have...

```
scope :sorted, -> { order("xoi DESC") }
```

I have "xoi" defined as...

def xoi
     passing + running
   end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort by a method added in Ruby. Instead, you can do:

```
scope :sorted, -> { select('*, (passing + running) as xoi').order('xoi DESC') }
```

provided, of course, that your `passing` and `running` attributes are columns in DB.

Comment: YES! I love you! You win! I will give you gold and silver! Seriously...now I understand the power of this community and appreciate it so much. Godspeed.

Answer (score 0):

xoi would need to be define as a column in your database for this to work.
Here xoi is defined in a ruby methods, so instead of sorting via a database you want to sort a collection via ruby, for this you can use sort_by such as:

```
@player = Roster.all
@player.sort_by(&:xoi)
```

Answer (score 0):

your `xoi` will not work in scope, It should be column in database If you defined inside condition:

```
scope :sorted, -> { order("passing + running") }
Roster.sorted.reverse
```